# How can I fix this uneven border?

Tags: html, css

In a table that I've made with HTML and CSS, the first column is of a different height than the rest?
The top of the column is uneven with the others to the right of it.

Do run the code snippet below. The column I'm referring to is the "Date joined / Name / Email" block.

How can I fix this?

My current code looks like this:

```css
<style>.table1 {
  border-spacing: 1px;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  align-content: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
}

</style>
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">

    <h2 style="margin: 11px; height: 37px;"><u>Table Test:</u></h2>

    <table class="table1" border="1" style="width:50%">

      <tr style="background-color:#D6EAF8">
        <td colspan="3" align="center" width="60%" style="height:30px"><b>Main</b></td>
        <td colspan="1" align="center" width="10%"><b>Email</b></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td rowspan="4" align="center">Date joined /<br> Name / Email</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td align="center">05022022</td>
        <td style="height:30px" align="center">Kimberly</td>
        <td align="center">kimberlyk@gmail.com</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td align="center">02152022</td>
        <td style="height:30px" align="center">Robert</td>
        <td align="center">robwayne@gmail.com</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td align="center">12232021</td>
        <td style="height:30px" align="center">Jessie</td>
        <td align="center">jessieanderson@gmail.com</td>
      </tr>

    </table>

  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: For your own sake and sanity please consider using Flex-box or Grid
- https://www.w3schools.com/csS/css3_flexbox.asp

- https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp

Comment: its perfectly fine to use a table for tabular data

Answer (score 0):

So you just had a little obfuscation in your colspans/rowspan attributes. Fixing the way you asked wouldn't align your column headers though and have just "Date Joined / Name / Email" centered on their own row though that wasn't very intuitive so I'm assuming you were maybe aiming for something closer to the example provided below. Cheers.

```css
<style>.table1 {
  border-spacing: 1px;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  align-content: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
}

</style>
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">

    <h2 style="margin: 11px; height: 37px;"><u>Table Test:</u></h2>

    <table class="table1" border="1" style="width:50%">

      <tr style="background-color:#D6EAF8">
        <th colspan="2" align="center" width="60%" style="height:30px"><b>Main</b></th>
        <th colspan="1" rowspan="2" align="center" width="10%"><b>Email</b></th>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td align="center">Date joined</td>
        <td align="center">Name</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td align="center">05022022</td>
        <td style="height:30px" align="center">Kimberly</td>
        <td align="center">kimberlyk@gmail.com</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td align="center">02152022</td>
        <td style="height:30px" align="center">Robert</td>
        <td align="center">robwayne@gmail.com</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td align="center">12232021</td>
        <td style="height:30px" align="center">Jessie</td>
        <td align="center">jessieanderson@gmail.com</td>
      </tr>

    </table>

  </div>

</body>
```